# How can I deploy an outlook addin with an sqlite database included into the project?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins

I am trying to display an outlook addin on a user's pc. This addinn has a small database, and it seems that when the extension begins to communicate with the db, it does not work. In visual studio I have not had any problems so I guess the problem is at the moment of creating the executable for the user to install the extension

Using CLickOnce, the addin is installed and displayed in the user's outlook, but when it must interact with the database, it does not work.
I have also tried adding a Setup project, to which I include the database, but this method does not even show the addin in the client's outlook

The database is located in a folder in the main directory, as follows: 
[image]

In app.config i use this related path:

```
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB\pluginDB.db;Version=3;"
```

And DataDirectory:

`string Path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
 string[] appPath = Path.Split(new string[] { "bin" },StringSplitOptions.None);
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", appPath[0]);`

And this works in visual studio

Comment: Where is the database located? (file with extension.sqlite3, .sqlite, .db).  Which extension are you using?  Are you specifying the full path of the file in addin?  Addin is probably expecting the database to be in same folder as executable.  Running for outlook the addin is being installed in a different location to it is not finding the database.  Is database on local machine or a network drive?

Comment: Can user open the file in Notepad?  The file may not have correct credentials for user to read.

Comment: I have updated the post with more info

Comment: When you installed software is there a BIN folder?  When  you run from c# there is always a bin folder.  If you take executable and put on another machine without VS there usually isn't a BIN.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried adding a Setup project, to which I include the database, but this method does not even show the addin in the client's outlook

The [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article describes the required steps for deploying Office solutions. Make sure that you did all steps described in the article.

> Using CLickOnce, the addin is installed and displayed in the user's outlook, but when it must interact with the database, it does not work.

It seems the add-in can't locate the DB file on the user machine. I'd recommend adding any log statements to see what happens on the target machine. Anyway, try to use the following folder instead of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` one:

```
  public static string AssemblyDirectory
  {
     get
     {
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
     }
  }
```